# embed CRL using itext 2.1.7

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

How to embed CRL while signing pdf using itext 2.1.7 ?
I was able to sign pdf with timestamp but it is not LTV enabled. I want to make it LTV enabled. CAn somebody help.

Comment: You will have to upgrade to a more recent iText version or implement the support for LTV yourself...